# Efficient way to count the amount lines obeying some condition

Tags: awk

I'm try counting the number of lines in a file which 4th field is greater than first filed by using awk command
I came up with this command:

```
awk '$4>$1 {print}' sampleFile | wc -l
```

Is there any better way to find the number rather than using `wc -l`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '$4 > $1 { count++ } END { print count }' file.txt
```

Comment: +1 : any awk, even (old)awk will process your highly portable code. Good luck to all.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't have multiple input feeds (i.e. `FNR` mirrors `NR`), one way to do this without needing an extra counter variable is simply to decrement `FNR` whenever condition is true, then the difference in the end will be your count :

```
mawk 'END { print NR - FNR } { FNR -= +$1 < +$4 }'
```